# Ruby STDERR & STDOUT log file on Mac

Tags: ruby, stdout

Where can I find the default log file on my Mac when I log using STDOUT eg. Logger.new(STDOUT).

```
l = Logger.new(STDOUT)
l.info 'my log'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find the default log file on my Mac when I log using `STDOUT` eg. `Logger.new(STDOUT)`.

Obviously, in the console window. Logging to standard output does not produce any hard copy of the log.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use a Mac, but I assume it would be just as with Linux (at the bottom they are cousins)

```
require 'logger'
l = Logger.new('logfile.log')
l.info 'my log'
```

***logfile.log*** would be in the same directory where u run this code.

Check [Rdoc Logger Class Help](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) for more information

Comment: This will log to stdout (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with logging. The logger writes to STDOUT, which has the same effect than if you write to STDOUT.

This means that it logs to wherever STDOUT is redirected to. This has nothing to do with Ruby, because you usually set up the redirection when you invoke the program, i.e. by the calling process (your shell). In this respect, the Mac (basically BSD Unix) is not different from Linux or Windows.